# Ionic/angular switching from sideview to tabview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

im currently using ionics sliding sideview for my navigation in my app but i want to switch to the new tabs. I have changed the code to make the tabs but $state.go doesn't seem to work any more. Here was the code for the old sliding navigation :

```
<ion-side-menus>

      <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content="">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced nav-title-slide-ios7">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>  
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-pane>

      <ion-side-menu side="left" class="main-menu">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>

          <ion-content has-header="true" ng-controller="SplashCtrl">

            <ion-list>
             <ion-item class="heading-item item item-avatar" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="app.profile">

          <div class="user-image-container">
            <pre-img ratio="_1_1" helper-class="rounded-image">
              <img class="user-image" ng-src="img/logo.jpg" spinner-on-load="">
            </pre-img>
          </div>
          <h2 class="greeting">{{welcomename}}</h2>
          <p class="message">Welcome back</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.google" ng-click="googleLoginClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">My Diary</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.history" ng-click="historyClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">Search</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.tasklist" ng-click="tasklistClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">Task List</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.myforms" ng-click="myFormsClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">Unsent Instructions ({{unsentFormsCount}})</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.banking" ng-click="bankingClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">Banking</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ng-click="logoutClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">Logout</h2>
        </ion-item>


            </ion-list>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>
```

The "XXclick" functions in the ng-clicks just call $stat.go's. Here is the new navigation :

(ive just added the top one to reduce the code )

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
<ion-content has-header="true" ng-controller="SplashCtrl">

  <ion-tab title="Diary" icon-off="ion-ios-calendar-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-calendar" ui-sref="utab.google" ng-click="googleLoginClick()">
    <ion-nav-view name="diary"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-content>
</ion-tabs>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First no need to use ion-content in tab. There should be issue in routing also. Can you update full code or create code pen? so I can help you. I think below code pen link will help you.

```
'http://codepen.io/nirmal25/pen/BzQxzX'
```

Comment: Its a rather big project!